# I could not return soap response

Tags: python, django, xml, soap, spyne

I need to write a soap service which gets soap request and return soap response. I could handle sending soap request with zeep client library, everythin correct. But i couldnt send any soap response it shows the same error:)

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, AnyDict
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.django import DjangoApplication

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from invoice.api.russian_webservice.complex_models import Consignor, Request1Type, Request31Type, Request91Type, CertificateMaximumType, CertificateMinimumType, Response91Type

from exim.models import ExportFSS, ImportFSS


class RussianIntegrationApiView(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Request91Type,
         _returns=AnyDict,
         _out_variable_name="Response91")
    def getResponse91(ctx, request91type):
        try:
            logging.info(
                f'Initialized objects {str(Request91Type).encode("utf-8")}')
            error_message = None
            error_code = None

            import_fss = ImportFSS.objects.create(
                number=request91type.certificate.number,
                given_date=datetime.strptime(
                    request91type.certificate.date, '%d.%m.%Y'),
                exporter_name=request91type.certificate.consignor.name,
                exporter_country=request91type.certificate.departure_country,
                exporter_address=request91type.certificate.consignor.place,
                importer_name=request91type.certificate.consignee.name,
                importer_country=request91type.certificate.destination_country,
                importer_address=request91type.certificate.consignee.place,
                transport_method=request91type.certificate.transport.declared_type,
                transport_number=request91type.certificate.transport.number,
                disinfected_date=datetime.strptime(
                    request91type.certificate.disinfection.date, '%d.%m.%Y'),
                treatment_method=request91type.certificate.disinfection.method,
                chemical=request91type.certificate.disinfection.chemical,
                duration_and_temperature=request91type.certificate.disinfection.temperature_times,
                concentration=request91type.certificate.disinfection.concentration,
                extra_info=request91type.certificate.additional_info,
            )
            return {
                "GUID": CertificateMinimumType.guid_generate(),
                "SendDateTime": "2022-04-11T19:50:11    ",  
                "Certificate": CertificateMinimumType.generate(),
                "Status": "Выдан",
                "StatusCode": "1601",
                "Inspector": ""
            }

        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(f'Exception occurred: {str(e)}')


def on_method_return_string(ctx):
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'soap11env', b'soapenv')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'tns', b'mun')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'GUID', b'm:GUID')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'SendDateTime', b'm:SendDateTime')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Act', b'm:Act')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Date', b'm:Date')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Number', b'm:Number')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Blanc', b'm:Blanc')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'OldDate', b'm:OldDate')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'CountryCode', b'm:CountryCode')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'ExpirationDate', b'm:ExpirationDate')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Canceled', b'm:Canceled')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'IssuePlace', b'm:IssuePlace')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Inspector', b'm:Inspector')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'InspectionResult', b'm:InspectionResult')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'InspectionResultCode', b'm:InspectionResultCode')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'InspectionResultReport', b'm:InspectionResultReport')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'InspectionType', b'm:InspectionType')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'InspectionTypeCode', b'm:InspectionTypeCode')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'Certificates', b'm:Certificates')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'Status', b'm:Status')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(
        b'StatusCode', b'm:StatusCode')
    ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'PDF', b'm:PDF')

    print("aaaa-------")
    print(ctx.out_string[0].decode('utf-8'))


RussianIntegrationApiView.event_manager.add_listener('method_return_string',
                                                     on_method_return_string)
application = Application([RussianIntegrationApiView],
                          'https://argusgate.fitorf.ru/srv/ws/uz3',
                          name='UzGosKarantinWSPortBinding',
                          in_protocol=Soap11(validator='soft'),
                          out_protocol=Soap11(),
                          )

russian_api_service = DjangoApplication(application)


def get_wsdl_file_russian(request):
    with open('apps/invoice/api/russian_webservice/russian.wsdl', 'r') as f:
        docs = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(docs, content_type='text/xml; charset=utf-8')


@csrf_exempt
def russian_service_dispatcher(request):

    if request.get_full_path() in ('/UzGosKarantinWebService/russian/?wsdl',
                                   '/UzGosKarantinWebService/russian?wsdl'):
        return get_wsdl_file_russian(request)
    return russian_api_service(request)
```

this is link for wsdl file : https://pastebin.com/459DAje1
this is for complex models: https://pastebin.com/KjV1tWWc

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CJTm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code you posted, your request name is `getResponse91` but according to the error PNG that you posted, you are sending a request for `Request91`

You need to fix either your request or change the function from getResponse91 to `Request91`

Comment: Thanks.fixed that but how i fill it with data from django model

Comment: I need the first one structured soap response but i get the second one in this code: https://pastebin.com/fRezP4vj

Comment: I can't only help you if I see some code

Comment: All related code i posted above